# <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert datatype object to datetime but I have this error :

```
<class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
```

Here is my code :

```
time_df = time_df.rename(columns={"TIME_START": "hour"})
time_df["hour"] = pd.to_datetime(time_df["hour"]).dt.time

data_h_df['hour'] = data_df['time_utc'].dt.time
data_h_df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(data_h_df["hour"]).dt.time
```

I have two dataframes, my problem is `hour` variable I want to change datatype object to datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to strings:

```
data_h_df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(data_h_df["hour"].astype(str)).dt.time
```

but why converted `times` to `datetimes` and then to `times`? In my opinion in `data_h_df['hour']` are datetimes, expected ouput before your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but I still have the error

Comment: @Data_ing - hmm, for me working perfectly. Tested `data_h_df = pd.DataFrame({'hour':[datetime.time(1, 9, 24), datetime.time(7, 9, 26)]})`

Comment: I tried this but the datatype is always object.

Comment: @Data_ing - yes, it is expected. `datetime.time` is object..

Comment: Ok, thank you for your explanations. I don't have the error anymore and I was able to merge my dataframes.